# Highcharts events to catch clicking on the slice of the donut chart, and get slice info from the event

Tags: events, highcharts, click, selection

I am using Highcharts to display a donut chart. When user clicks on a slice of the donut, we want to catch the event and get the slice information(key, label, value etc). From the highcharts document, looks like selection is the right event, but i tried to catch it, it didn't trigger when I click one of the slices. I also added click event, this event was triggered when I clicked outside the slices, not on the slices, and also in the click event, it has xAxis and yAxis, not the exact information I am looking for.  Could anyone who is familiar with highcharts help please ? I have a codesandbox sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/qw8r8

Some code snippet(part of chartOptions) as below:

```
   chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Overpass',
        },
        zoomType: 'xy',
        events: {
            click: (event:any) => {
                console.log("click event fired");
            },
            selection(event:any) {
                console.log("selection event fired");
            },
            render() {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

the render event can be triggered. Click event is triggered only when user click outside or inside the donut chart (not on slices). selection event is never trigered when user click slices.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `chart.events` use `plotOptions.series.point.events` or `series.point.events`, example:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.point.events

Comment: Thanks ppotaczek. It worked after i switched to use plotOptions.series.point.events, like select and unselect events, and event contains the information like index and name which are what I need.